# How to find NLP words count and plot it?

Tags: python, nlp, seaborn

I am doing some NLP work

my original dataframe is `df_all`

```
Index    Text
1        Hi, Hello, this is mike, I saw your son playing in the garden...
2        Besides that, sometimes my son studies math for fun...
3        I cannot believe she said that. she always says such things...
```

I converted my texts to BOW data frame

so my dataframe `df_BOW` looks like this now

```
Index    Hi   This   my   son   play   garden ...
1        3    6      3    0     2       4
2        0    2      4    4     3       1
3        0    2      0    7     3       0
```

I want to find how many times each word appeared in the corpus

```
cnt_pro = df_all['Text'].value_counts()
plt.figure(figsize=(12,4))
sns.barplot(cnt_pro.index, cnt_pro.values, alpha=0.8)
plt.ylabel('Number of Occurrences', fontsize=12)
plt.xlabel('Word', fontsize=12)
plt.xticks(rotation=90)
plt.show();
```

to get top words like this

[image]

but I get this chart that shows no info

[image: I w]

How can I fix that?

Comment: Applying "value_counts()" on "df_all.Text" is probably not what you want (counting how often the same text appears).

Comment: @MichaelButscher so which function shall i choose?

Comment: Use the "sum" and "transpose" methods on the "df_BOW" dataframe.

Comment: @MichaelButscher i am new to Python, how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how you are creating `df_BOW` but it's not in an ideal format for plotting.

```py
df_all = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "text": [
            "Hi, Hello, this is mike, I saw your son playing in the garden",
            "Besides that, sometimes my son studies math for fun",
            "I cannot believe she said that. she always says such things",
        ]
    }
)
```

Similarly to [RF Adriaansen's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67982527/3279716) we can use a regex to extract the words, but instead we will only use pandas methods:

```py
counts = df["text"].str.findall(r"(\w+)").explode().value_counts()
```

- [`Series.str.findall`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.findall.html): apply the regex `(\w+)` to capture all words. This returns a `Series` of lists.
- [`Series.explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.explode.html): Transform each element of a list-like to a row.
- [`Series.value_counts`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html): Return a Series containing counts of unique values.

`counts` is a series with the index being the word and the value being the count:

```
son          2
she          2
I            2
...
says         1
garden       1
math         1
Name: text, dtype: int64
```

Then to plot:

```py
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(6,5))
sns.barplot(x=counts.index, y=counts.values, ax=ax)
ax.set_ylabel('Number of Occurrences', fontsize=12)
ax.set_xlabel('Word', fontsize=12)
ax.xaxis.set_tick_params(rotation=90)
```

[image]

If you jsut want the to N most frequent words you can use [`nlargest`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.nlargest.html) like so:

```py
top_10 = counts.nlargest(10)
```

and plot in the same way.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `collections.Counter` to count the words:

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
from collections import Counter
import re
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = ['Hi, Hello, this is mike, I saw your son playing in the garden', 'Besides that, sometimes my son studies math for fun', 'I cannot believe she said that. she always says such things']
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['text'])

df['text_split'] = df['text'].apply(lambda x: re.findall(r'\w+', x)) #split sentences to words with regex
words = [item.lower() for sublist in df['text_split'].tolist() for item in sublist] # flattens the list of lists and lowers the words

counted_words = Counter(words)
counted_df = pd.DataFrame(counted_words.items(), columns=['word', 'count']).sort_values('count', ascending=False).reset_index(drop=True) #create new df from counter

plt.figure(figsize=(12,4))
sns.barplot(data=counted_df[:10], x='word', y='count', alpha=0.8) #plot only the top 10 by slicing the df
plt.ylabel('Number of Occurrences', fontsize=12)
plt.xlabel('Word', fontsize=12)
plt.xticks(rotation=90)
plt.show()
```

Result:

[image]